# I Made a wrong transaction https://stellarchain.io

Tags: accounts, xlm, ledger, ledger-nano

My apologies, but I couldn’t find many channels to address my problems, hence I am writing this post.

I made a wrong transaction to a donation address of XLM GAI3GJ2Q3B35AOZJ36C4ANE3HSS4NK7WI6DNO4ZSHRAX6NG7BMX6VJER at https://stellarchain.io . I was checking an address to see if there are any transactions made, but if the address is new  with zero history the page stellarchain.io redirect to its donation page, which I assume it is my address. This was the amount 8675.7778528 XLM. It was made by an account at Bitvavo. See attached my proof.

[image: stellarchain]

I am just wondering if the XLM community can help and reverse the transaction please? That would be great. Please send to this address GDUQ7IJV2EVPTFCYDYOQB6APWVCMTBARXM65JHZ4Y7YS2BAQANVFSURK, as the other address is from an exchange. Sorry I was doing this in a haste. Many thanks.

Kind regards,

Quyen Nguyen

Comment: That's like 400 USD. Tell me about a big fail...

Comment: I made a transaction and went to the donation address which was a systematic error by blockchain

Answer (score 2):

Lumen transactions can not be reversed.

Comment: I do hope the person who holds donation account GAI3GJ2Q3B35AOZJ36C4ANE3HSS4NK7WI6DNO4ZSHRAX6NG7BMX6VJER at stellarchain.io will return the payment.